# Lost data in Google Chrome webform

Tags: google-chrome, data-recovery, google-chrome-extensions

I was typing information into a long web form in Google Chrome using the Grammarly Chrome extension to check my spelling. Just as I was about to save my work the page crashed and the form was wiped clean. Is there any way to get my data back? I've tried Ctrl-Z but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to recover the form data as anything on the form won't be saved anywhere until you save it. I could recommend using a form recovery tool such as 'Typio' in the future if required.